# installed drupal site locally but not working (XAMPP)

Tags: migrations

I want to install the site from the server locally so I can test changes before performing them.

So:

1. I exported the database and installed it locally
2. I downloaded all the files that were inside the site root folder and put them in a root folder locally (but with another name)
3. I changed the parameter `$db_url` and `$base_url`

The problem is that the front page is shown correctly but when I click to go to another page from the menu it says:

[an error occurred while processing this directive] The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Anyone have any idea?

NOTE: I just noticed that the url is something like this: `http://localhost/root//articles/article-one`

Thank you

Comment: have you cleared drupal cache ?

Comment: i went through command line and cleared all the cache_ tables with the truncate command. is this what you mean?

Comment: your local server is not set up properly. is `root` the drupal folder ?

Comment: @kantu yes it's the name of the folder that the drupal side resides in. If i install drupal platform alone it is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are there any custom rewrite rules in your htaccess file? when something similar happened in my case, I had `RewriteBase /` set in my *.htaccess* file from the actual deployment environment that had to be commented. Identified this by enabling a log in my local httpd.conf on how the URLs were translated with

```
RewriteLog "custom/folder/path"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

to have a better idea of how the rules translated the URLs and where i messed up, hope this has some significance in solving the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

One reason for this can be 'the apache server's rewrite mod is not enabled'.

See if

> localhost/sitename/index.php?q=user/login

is working.

If that is working then try enabling Clean URL (`sudo a2enmod rewrite for LAMP`).

Few links that can be related to the problems.

http://drupal.org/node/1186762

http://drupal.org/node/333675

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to clear the menu cache but after an import I always clear all cache to be safe. Also try a search in your imported db for your online url..?

Also for Drupal Local dev, have a look at [Dev Desktop](https://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop), I used to use XAMPP then moved to WAMP and now use Dev Desktop as I pretty much soley develop Drupal now.

Comment: i cleared the cache with the truncate command. But the problem remains. what do you mean with the online url?thanks for the reply. Also i want to ask if the browser's cache is disabled then the cache of drupal has any effect?

Comment: When you exported the Database, where was the source, if it was online I would search for the URL in your database to make sure there is nothing you need to change from domain.com to localhost etc? - also make sure you brought down the htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be with the links in your site.

```
<a href="/awesome_page">Awesome Page</a>
```

If absolute links are used then this will work fine in your live site.
`www.mysite.com/awesome_page` is valid but when you try to work with your local i.e `http://localhost/drupal/front_page` the link Awesome page will now actually point to `http://localhost/awesome_page`. 
Quick work around will be to set up your local like live site. 
Add an entry in your hosts file like `127.0.0.1 www.mysite.local` Add a virtual host entry(httpd-vhosts.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/apache2.2.8/htdocs/drupal"
</VirtualHost>
```

restart apache server and you will be able to access http://www.mysite.local from your local server and all links will work.

Comment: i tried to make a virtual host but still throws the same message. (but that was a very good information that you gave)

Answer (score 1):

Check if .htaccess file is exists in site root folder.